# custom error page - can't get into handler

Tags: php, kohana-3.3

I'm trying to add my custom pages. I'm using Kohana 3.3. The official documentation states that I should ovveride the method `hander` of native `Kohana_Exception` class. This is pretty easy to do so I've done that. Now I'm expecting that Kohana would call that method every time an exception or an error occurs. But this is not the case. I've found 2 catch blocks where an exception is caught inside `execute_request` method of `Kohana_Request_Client_Internal` class.

**First catch**

```
catch (HTTP_Exception $e)
{
    // Get the response via the Exception
    $response = $e->get_response();
}
```

**Second catch**

```
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Generate an appropriate Response object
    $response = Kohana_Exception::_handler($e);
}
```

As you can see, none of the catch blocks calls `handler` method overriden by me.

Setting your own exception handler `set_exception_handler` has no effect since it is applied only to uncaught exceptions and the exceptions like `404` are thrown and caught.

No problems with run-time errors though. This block catches them and explicitly calls overriden `handler` method.

```
if (Kohana::$errors AND $error = error_get_last() AND in_array($error['type'], 

    Kohana::$shutdown_errors))
    {
        // Clean the output buffer
        ob_get_level() AND ob_clean();

        // Fake an exception for nice debugging
        Kohana_Exception::handler(new ErrorException($error['message'], $error['type'], 0, $error['file'], $error['line']));

        // Shutdown now to avoid a "death loop"
        exit(1);
    }
```

So my question how do I set up everything to have custom error page for Exception and HTTP_Exception?

PS. I can ovveride HTTP_Exception_404 and HTTP_Exception_500 to have my custom error page displayed, but I don't think that's the best option since it could work for these two, but overriding all possible HTTP_Exceptions is not a good way to go.

PS2. Or I can set my custom view in `bootstrap.php`:

```
Kohana_Exception::$error_view = 'custom_error.tpl';
```

Also don't like that solution.

Comment: Have you read all this page : http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages ? Can you show use the code of your handler class ?

Comment: Yes I have. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### All links to Kohana's documentation in this post are for version 3.3

You won't get what you want by overwriting just one method. Below I explain the methods that you can overwrite in order to achieve what you want. Just make just sure you put the right code in the right method.

Don't try to do everything in one place. While it will be all in one place is will most likely become a mess.

---

### Kohana_Exception::handler()

[Kohana_Exception::handler()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#handler) is for when exceptions reach the exception handler or like you showed, in the shutdown handler. The last chance you have to display a nice error page in production environments. It outputs the result of [Kohana_exception::_handler()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#_handler), which is a Response object, and is therefor not suited to be called inside [Request_Client_Internal::execute_response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request_Client_Internal#execute_request).

For production: Log the original exception. Since this scenario matches the description of [HTTP Status Code 500 (Internal Server Error)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1) Kohana_Exception::handler() should display a 500 error page.

During development you probably want to call `parent::handler()`.

### Kohana_Exception::_handler()

[Kohana_Exception::_handler()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#_handler) return a Response object, so it is suited to be called in [Request_Client_External::execute_response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request_Client_Internal#execute_request), [Kohana_Exception::handler()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#handler) and [View::__toString()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/View#__toString).

### HTTP_Exception::get_response()

[HTTP_Exception::get_response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/HTTP_Exception#get_response) will get called for exceptions extending HTTP_Exception, with the exception of exceptions extending HTTP_Exception_Expected. A few examples of exceptions extending HTTP_Expected_Exception are the 3xx and 401 HTTP_Exceptions.

By default it returns [Kohana_Exception::response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#response).
Overwrite it in specific exceptions to return specific responses for said exception.
Overwrite it in HTTP_Exception when you want the replace the default response.

### Kohana_Exception::response()

[Kohana_Exception::response()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Kohana_Exception#response) is responsible for collecting the data needed to render the Kohana_Exception::$error_view template. An example of output can be seen on the [kohana/errors page of the userguide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/errors#example).

Change Kohana_Exception::$error_view when you want a different layout for the same data.
Overwrite Kohana_Exception::response() to replace the entire thing.

PS. Kevin pointed you to the 3.2 documentation. How to do this is very different for 3.2 and 3.3.

Comment: Thanks! I assume that these _Change Kohana_Exception::$error_view when you want a different layout for the same data. Overwrite Kohana_Exception::response() to replace the entire thing._ are the only options, right?

Comment: No, I would prefer the overwrite the other three and don't touch Kohana_Exception::response()